# Placing HTML in div from resource files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to place a HTML formatted text from my resources file to a `<div>` in my aspx page, but it places the text as is, not as HTML.

**myResources.resx:**
[image]

**myPage.apsx:**

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Resources" %>
....
....

<div>
    <%: myResources.myKey %>
</div>
```

This results in:

`This is the first line.<br>This is the second line.`

When my wanted output is:

```
This is the first line.
This is the second line.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `<%: myResources.myKey %>` encodes your string. This is simple. You can do the following:

```
<div>
    <%= myResources.myKey %> 
</div>
```

`<%= value %>` will NOT encode the value.

Comment: Great. Working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this should be avoided, but sometimes it is practically unavoidable.

You can use the @Html.Raw method inside your view, e.g. `@Html.Raw(STRING FROM RESX FILE HERE)`

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain exactly what I should do